# how\where do I initialize a value so all listeners are executed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a an AngularJS view that includes something like this:

```
<select ng-change="shop.updateSizes()" ng-model="shop.color" ng-options="color.name for color in COLORS"></select>
```

The change method looks something like this in my controller:

```
shop.updateSizes = function () {
    this.sizes = this.color.sizes;
    this.updateSomethingElse(); //*

    return this;
}
```

How do I initialize the color and have the listener (updateSizes) execute?

Also, bonus question: is the line marked with a * considered good practice? Alternatively, I could put a listener in the controller object for sizes and have it execute updateSomethingElse().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation `ng-change` only fires for user input. It does not fire if you change the model in code. As mentioned in `ng-change` documentation

> It will not be evaluated:
>
> if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has
>
> not changed if the input has continued to be invalid since the model
>
> will stay null if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

Wherever you initialize the `color` you need to call this method manually.

```
$scope.shop.color=$scope.COLORS[0];  //selects first value
$scope.shop.updateSizes()
```

Comment: Thanks. Are initializations like that usually put straight in the controller or in one of its methods?

Comment: You can add directly to controller. But i prefer to create method like init() and call it inside the controller function. The init can contain all initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

You set the initial value of color in your controller with

```
$scope.color = 'some-color';
```

Angular should handle your ng-change directives automatically and fire that method in your controller.

If you think you need to add events and listners yourself, you should read up on some Angular guides, it basically does everything for you.